# how to do XQuery - tsql

Tags: t-sql, xquery

I got this XML.

```
<ArrayOfGuid xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <guid>475B07C8-CDEA-4000-BAAE-485336190E10</guid>
     <guid>6E5B87BC-CF80-4AB2-939E-ED951FA604AB</guid>
     <guid>31BFDA60-3BB2-49DC-8C69-10F6E1B540CA</guid>
</ArrayOfGuid>
```

Need to get the results like

```
BatchGUID
475B07C8-CDEA-4000-BAAE-485336190E10
6E5B87BC-CF80-4AB2-939E-ED951FA604AB
31BFDA60-3BB2-49DC-8C69-10F6E1B540CA
```

Somehow I am stuck with

```
DECLARE @BatchGUID XML

SET @BatchGUID = '<ArrayOfGuid xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                      <guid>475B07C8-CDEA-4000-BAAE-485336190E10</guid>
                      <guid>6E5B87BC-CF80-4AB2-939E-ED951FA604AB</guid>
                      <guid>31BFDA60-3BB2-49DC-8C69-10F6E1B540CA</guid>
                    </ArrayOfGuid>'

DECLARE @t_xml TABLE
(
    BatchGUID XML
)

INSERT INTO @t_xml
SELECT @BatchGUID

SELECT C.* FROM @t_xml
cross apply (select name.value('guid[1]', 'uniqueidentifier') as [BatchGUID] 
from BatchGUID.nodes('//ArrayOfGuid/guid') as c(name)) as C
```

This is returning me

```
BatchGUID
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Need to know what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so very close!

Your problem is that you're selecting the value of the `guid[1]` node from within the `guid` node. Of course, the `guid` node doesn't contain any children - you want to select the value from that node itself (which is expressed as `.`)

```
SELECT C.* FROM @t_xml
cross apply (select name.value('.', 'uniqueidentifier') as [BatchGUID]
from @BatchGUID.nodes('//ArrayOfGuid/guid') as c(name)) as C
```